# Generators of ideals in polynomial rings over commutative rings.

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

This is my first question; I hope it worthy of this awesome forum and its members.

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, perhaps with unit, perhaps not.  As usual let $R[x]$
denote the ring of polynomials over $R$, and let $I$ be an ideal in $R[x]$.  Let
$D(I)$ be the subset of $I$ consisting of all $f(x) \in I$ of minimal degree.  It is
well known from elementary algebra that in the event that $R$ is a field, $D(I)$
consists of essentially one element $d(x)$ (up to multiplication by a unit of $R$),
and that $I$ is the principal ideal generated by $d(x)$:  $I = (d(x)) = Rd(x)$.
In the case of general commutative $R$, does $D(I)$ generate $I$ in the sense that
any $f(x) \in I$ may be written $f(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^{m} f_{i}(x)d_i(x)$ with $d_{i}(x)\in D(I)$ and $f_{i}(x) \in R[x]$?  Does the existence of $1 \in R$ make any difference?

Comment: I am afraid that your question is somewhat below the awesome level of this awesome forum. Anyway, this is wrong already for $R=\mathbb{Z}:$ the ideal $(2,x)$ of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is not generated by the degree 0 polynomials contained in it. (I hope this wasn't a homework question, by the way!)

Comment: It looks as though you're trying to rediscover the proof of Hilbert's basis theorem though. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert's_basis_theorem

Comment: First of all, thanks to Victor Prostak for providing a negative answer to my to my question.  Upon re-thinking it, looking at the
structure of $(2, x)$ in $Z[x]$, I remembered the ascending chain condition from a graduate course in abstract algebra I took quite awhile ago, and from several books on ring theory I read in its wake.  I soon discovered the wiki page on the Hilbert basis theorem
Simon Wadsely mentioned; and yes, that is the kind of thing I was reaching for, though I haven't fully digested it yet.  Finally, I assure all it was *not* homework; I pursued the question
on my own.


Comment: there is no reason why this should be closed.